# Broken symlinks

Tags: php, symfony, assets

I'm using assestic and symlinks for js/css files. It works fine on the local pc but the paths are broken when I upload the project on the production server

Here is the output of ls on the production server
ls

```
Framework -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/public/
```

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ is a path on the local pc

How to fix that?

Comment: Recreate them on the production server?

Answer (score 0):

You should run this on deployment:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```